# how can I extend root partition with unallocated space before that?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I dual booted windows 10 and ubuntu 
my hard drive is 1 tb 
first part of hard disk about 700 gb is windows 
then second part was another windows drive with 200 gb space 
that I recently deleted it 
and last part is 100 gb for whole ubuntu without separating home and root and ... 
now I want to extend ubuntu with 200gb unallocated space and I can't 
what should I do 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hErCS.png)
thank you

Comment: You can't. You need to move it first then expand.

Comment: Edit your question and show me a screenshot of `gparted`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot from a live disk, since you can't manipulate a partition you booted from.

Then run gparted.

https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions